# function if with type cell

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I have data type cell like this:

```
A = 'red' 'red' green' 'red'
B = 'red' 'blue' 'red' 'green'
C = 'green' 'red' green' 'blue'
D = 'blue' 'red' 'green' 'red'
E = 'green' 'blue' 'red' 'green'
```

then I mix in one cell like this:

```
X = {A{:},B{:},C{:},D{:},E{:}}
```

and I tabulate like this:

```
Y = tabulate(X)
```

so I can get the result:

```
'red'  '9'   '45'
'green' '7'  '35'
'blue' '4'  '20'
```

If I want to classify my data like:

```
if 'red' > 90% and 'green' <10% the result is "good"
if 'red' between 70 and 90 % and the result is "ok"
if 'red < 60% the result is "bad"
```

I can not use `if` in cell because when I use `==` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I try this (and beforehand change the `A{:},B{:},...` stuff to `A,B,...` if I input it manually; probably not needed in your case; in your case, `[A B C D E ...]` should work as well...), I get a `X` array like this:

It looks like this:

```
>> X={'red' 'red' 'green' 'blue' 'green'}

X = 

    'red'    'red'    'green'    'blue'    'green'

>>
```

If that is the case, your `Y` will contain the numerical data in numerical format, not with a `%` sign somewhere. `Y` will be a cell array with a string column and 2 numerical columns:

```
>> Y=tabulate(X)

Y = 

    'red'      [2]    [40]
    'green'    [2]    [40]
    'blue'     [1]    [20]
```

Now I can put the stuff together. Just as an example:

```
Z = cell2struct(Y(:,3), Y(:,1))
```

Here, I take the 2rd column of the cell array as data and the 1st one as field names for a to-be-created struct. So that will result in

```
>> Z=cell2struct(Y(:,3), Y(:,1))

Z = 

      red: 40
    green: 40
     blue: 20
```

> Why does it so? The 1st argument are the data to be put into the fields of the struct, which is, in our case, the "percentage" column. The 2nd argument gives the corresponding field names, in our case the "color" column. So in `Z` the field `red` gets the value `40`, `green` gets `40` and `blue` gets `20`.)

Then I can do

```
if Z.red > 90 && Z.green < 10 % why this 2nd condition? The 1st should be enough...
    result = 'good'
elseif Z.red > 70
    result = 'ok'
else
    result = 'bad'
end
```

or something alike (you didn't specify what should happen between 60 and 70 percent...)

Comment: please explain me more deeper about convert from cell to struct...thanks @glglgl God bless

Comment: `help cell2struct` didn't help? I'll return in an hour or so, then I might add some explanation.

Comment: i still didn't understand with Z = cell2struct(Y(:,3), Y(:,1)) , why i can be like that?thanks

Comment: @saut not better? If no, what is unclear in [`help cell2struct`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/cell2struct.html)? There are so many examples...

Comment: when i change from A{:},B{:},... stuff to A,B,...), it can't work to tabulate..but when i use A{:},B{:},... it worked...

Comment: the result in command window is ??? Error using ==> cell2struct
Number of field names must match number of fields in new structure..and if it worked, what variable i can use for input in GUI?

Comment: please explain to me how you can get Z = cell2struct(Y(:,3), Y(:,1)) especially (Y(:,3), Y(:,1))...maybe i can learn from it...thanks

Comment: i'm sorry, if i change the condition (look my first question) i have three color red, green, and blue...in the same condition, how i can use to clasiffy it? thanks

Comment: oke, but please one more time explain me how you can get Z = cell2struct(Y(:,3), Y(:,1)) especially (Y(:,3), Y(:,1))...why you put the number 3 and 1...thanks

Comment: Because the 3rd column are the data and the 1st column the field names.

Comment: oke don't worry...:-)...if you don't mind how if the condition i change like now, how to classify it? i use it X = {A{:},B{:},C{:},D{:},E{:}} and it worked, but how if i want to classify it?thanks

Comment: Just the data have changed, but not the procedure as such, so I would say, exactly the same way?

Comment: but why it show in command window ??? Error using ==> cell2struct
Invalid field name "blue"?

Comment: is there any impact if the name has space for example "blue green'?

Comment: how can i plotting a group data like using 

    gscatter(x,y,group,clr,sym,siz)

but i want to use it with 3D...
i tried `gscatter(x,y,z,group,clr,sym,siz)
but it doesn't work...

when i use 

    scatter3(x,y,clr,sym,siz)

it can't use the group...please help..